# How to dynamically generate a div and make it dragable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I am trying to create dynamic `divs` `onClick` of a button, but I also want to make the newly added `divs` to be `draggable`. How I can achieve this functionality?

**HTML**

Drag me around

Drag me around

Drag me around

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#draggable-2" ).draggable();
$( "#draggable-3" ).draggable();
});
```

What I want to do is that I need to create the divs dynamically on a click and apply the same `draggable` functionality to them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just have to append a new div to your container and make it draggable.

```
var nDraggable = 3;

$('#yourButton').click(function(){
  nDraggable++;
  $("#container").append('<div id="draggable-'+nDraggable'">Drag me around</div>');
  $("#draggable-"+nDraggable).draggable();
});
```

Is this what are you looking for?

Comment: yeah somehow,but I have to give this `draggable-4` a dynamic name, say it could be `draggable-num-passed-in-parameter`

Comment: You can use a global variable or another way that counts how many div with id starting with "draggable-" there are.  Which one do you prefer?

Comment: could you please edit your answer with the one with global variable thing? I cannot do it in a loop as I don't have any limit of adding divs

Comment: I've edited :) I suppose that you know how many draggable divs you already have